# Ascii Print file to PDF

Tags: java, file, pdf, printing, ascii

How to convert an ascii print file ( text file with line feed and form feed ctrl characters) into a PDF Document with the pre printed stationery as template or background image. How can this be done in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PDF using either one of two ways:

- In Java code using iText
- By creating an FO using something like Velocity (mapping your text data into a template) and running it through an FO transformer to create a PDF.

That gets you the PDF.  You can print it by either opening it in Adobe Reader and printing from there OR by sending it to a printer using the Java print API.